# Get Text for XML-Node including childnodes (or something like this)

Tags: python, xml

I have to get the pure text out of a xml-node and its child nodes, or what else these strange inner-tags are:

Example-Nodes:

```
<BookTitle>
<Emphasis Type="Italic">Z</Emphasis>
 = 63 - 100
</BookTitle>
```

or:

```
<BookTitle>
Mtn
<Emphasis Type="Italic">Z</Emphasis>
 = 74 - 210
</BookTitle>
```

I have to get:

```
Z = 63 - 100
Mtn Z = 74 - 210
```

Remember, this is just an example! There could be any type of "Child-Nodes" inside the BookTitle-Node, and all I need is the pure Text inside BookTitle.

I tried:

```
tagtext = root.find('.//BookTitle').text
print tagtext
```

but .text can't deal with this strange xml-nodes and gives me a "NoneType" back

Regards & Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the `text` of the `BookTitle` node, it's the `tail` of the `Emphasis` node. So you should do something like:

```
def parse(el):
    text = el.text.strip() + ' ' if el.text.strip() else ''
    for child in el.getchildren():
        text += '{0} {1}\n'.format(child.text.strip(), child.tail.strip())
    return text
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> root = et.fromstring('''
    <BookTitle>
    <Emphasis Type="Italic">Z</Emphasis>
     = 63 - 100
    </BookTitle>''')
>>> print parse(root)
Z = 63 - 100
```

And for:

```
>>> root = et.fromstring('''
<BookTitle>
Mtn
<Emphasis Type="Italic">Z</Emphasis>
 = 74 - 210
</BookTitle>''')
>>> print parse(root)
Mtn Z = 74 - 210
```

Which should give you a basic idea what to do.

**Update:** Fixed the whitespace...

Comment: Thanks, I got errors when the tail was empty or the text was empty, so I did this: `def parse(el):
    text = ''
    if el.text:
        text = el.text.strip()
    for child in el.getchildren():
        if child.text:
           text += child.text.strip()
        if child.tail:
           text += child.tail.strip()
    return text
` 
Which seems to be working. If I could simplify this, please tell me :)

Comment: Yes, you'll have to check if the `tail` or `text` are `None`, I forgot to include that check. I assumed from your example that they will always exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the minidom parser. Here is an example:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def strip_tags(node):
    text = ""
    for child in node.childNodes:
        if child.nodeType == doc.TEXT_NODE:
            text += child.toxml()
        else:
            text += strip_tags(child)
    return text

doc = minidom.parse("<your-xml-file>")

text = strip_tags(doc)
```

The strip_tags recursive function will browse the xml tree and extract the text in order.